# The RSelenium web driver stops working after a specific amount of time if left idle

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, browser, rselenium

So I am using RSelenium in R to scrape data from Instagram. What I am trying to do is to gather the IDs of the followers of a page for example. So I need to load the page, click on the followers of that page and scroll down the list until I get like 10000 IDs from the page source. Then I parse the page source and extract the IDs. But this needs time as the list of followers needs to be loaded constantly. The problem is that after a specific amount of time, the webdriver stops working. The browser does not close, It is still there, but I can not get the page source using the $getPageSource() function (I have debugged the code and that's where the it takes forever).
Note that if you start the web driver and leave it idle for some time the browser closes automatically. To avoid that you can simply refresh the page and this will postpone the closing. But in my case which I explained above I can't simply refresh the page because everything then starts from the beginning and I have to scroll down and load the IDs again and so on. 
I was wondering if anyone knows how I should deal with this problem. Or if the problem is due to web driver idleness at all.